# What are the automatic responses you can buy with Unicoins?

Tags: support, unicoins, unicorns, jeff-atwood

Will a unicorn respond this question with something encouraging? I hope all the bacon I spent on this was worth it.

Comment: I hope the moderators will not get away with this by just saying it was a joke. If it were, they have been lying. It is offending. I don't understand what is funny about it.

Answer (score 5):

I am intrigued by your ideas and would like to subscribe to your newsletter.

Comment: I feel bad for upvoting this past π.

Comment: @michaelb958 You are really posting the wrong comment. What you should be posting is, “Why does it matter?”